# Why does my simple calculator crashes when i don't give the second operand and press equal?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android development. I was trying to implement a simple calculator using Kotlin. All the functionalities are working as expected except when I just input my first operand and operator but don't give my second operand and press equal instead it crashes.

Apparently what I got form the error is it's trying to execute "inputValue = binding.tvInput.text.toString()" but failing because their's no value in tvInput.

I think I have written an if statement in onEquals function to handle this, but it isn't working.

here's the code for your reference:

Please Help!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:maxLength="12"
        tools:text="Result"
        android:textSize="48sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOperator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:maxLength="1"
        tools:text="Operator"
        android:textSize="48sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:maxLength="12"
        tools:text="Input"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="7" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="8" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="9" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onOperator"
            android:text="/" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="4" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="5" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="6" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onOperator"
            android:text="*" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="1" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="2" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="3" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onOperator"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDecimalPoint"
            android:text="." />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            android:text="0" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClear"
            android:text="clr" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onOperator"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onEquals"
            android:text="=" />
        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onDelete"
            android:text="DEL" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.jeetkabiraj.calculatorapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import com.jeetkabiraj.calculatorapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.jeetkabiraj.calculatorapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate
import java.lang.ArithmeticException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var lastNumaric = false
    var lastDot = false
    var inputValue: String = ""
    var result: String = ""
    var operator: String = ""
    var finalResult: Double = 0.0
    var TAG = "Message"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewBinding()
    }

    private fun viewBinding() {
        binding = inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    fun onDigit(view: View){
        binding.tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
        lastNumaric = true
    }

    fun onClear(view: View) {
        binding.tvInput.text = ""
        lastNumaric = false
        lastDot = false
    }

    fun onDecimalPoint(view: View){
        if(lastNumaric && !lastDot){
            binding.tvInput.append(".")
            lastDot = true
            lastNumaric = false
        }
    }

    fun onOperator(view: View){



        operator = (view as Button).text.toString()

            if(result == ""){
                result = binding.tvInput.text.toString()
                binding.tvResult.text = result
                binding.tvOperator.text = operator
                binding.tvInput.text = ""
        }
        else{
                binding.tvOperator.text = operator
                binding.tvInput.text = ""
            }
    }

    fun onEquals(view: View){


        if((binding.tvOperator.text != "") && (binding.tvResult.text != "") && (binding.tvInput.text != "")){

            result = binding.tvResult.text.toString()
            inputValue = binding.tvInput.text.toString()
            operator = binding.tvOperator.text.toString()

            var op1: Double = result.toDouble()
            Log.e(TAG, "inputValue is? " +binding.tvInput.text)
            var op2: Double = inputValue.toDouble()

            when(operator){
                "+" -> finalResult = op1 + op2
                "-" -> finalResult = op1 - op2
                "*" -> finalResult = op1 * op2
                "/" -> {
                    try {
                        finalResult = op1 / op2
                    } catch (e: ArithmeticException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
            binding.tvResult.text = finalResult.toString()
            binding.tvInput.text = ""
            binding.tvOperator.text = ""

        } else{
            binding.tvInput.text = "Error"
        }

    }

    fun onDelete(view: View){
        binding.tvInput.text = ""
        binding.tvResult.text = ""
        binding.tvOperator.text = ""
        result = ""
        inputValue = ""
        operator= ""
        finalResult = 0.0
        lastDot = false
        lastNumaric = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the exception too

Comment: where should i add it and what exception, I am new please elaborate

Comment: Question was about the error you get. Could you provide more info about it, preferably a stack trace?

Comment: try out this https://github.com/bitactro/Basic_Calculator_Android_App . Its in java but works perfectly fine

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.jeetkabiraj.calculatorapp.MainActivity.onEquals(MainActivity.kt:83)

Comment: Are you the person who asked the question in the first place? Because you use a different username right now. If this is the error then the description of the problem is incorrect. It said the problem was with `toString()` line, but it was with `toDouble()`. I suggest replacing these `!= ""` checks with `toDoubleOrNull()` and checking for nulls. You can't really be sure that users will put a valid double to a text field and `toDoubleOrNull()` checks for both invalid doubles and any empty values.

Comment: Yes i am the same person i just changed my name for stackoverflow, and thank you for the reply I solved the issue it was throwing a NumberFormatException that's why my app was crashing, I just added a try catch block to resolve the issue. Your solution will also work, I think I'll try it out. Thanks for replying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((binding.tvOperator.text != "") && (binding.tvResult.text != "") && (binding.tvInput.text != ""))
```

I think the problem is in this line. Instead of text != "" you should write text.toString().equals("")

```
if(!(binding.tvOperator.text.toString().equals("")) && !(binding.tvResult.text.toString().equals("")) && !(binding.tvInput.text.toString().equals("")))
```

Comment: This is the same in Kotlin.

Comment: No, it's not. getText() or in this case text will return CharSequence! and we want the value stored in the text

Comment: I was talking mostly about replacing `!=` with `equals()`, but you are right that if `text` is a `CharSequence` then we need to convert it to String.